# SimpleCursor Adapter

Tags: android, sqlite

I am getting data from sqlite manger or asset folder and i am perfect  while retrieving data using simplecursor adapter but how to do pagenation using cursor adapter please help me this is my code

```
public Cursor PreviousElectionTrends1(SQLiteDatabase db2)
{

    String[] columns=new  String[]{"voter_basic_info_id","report_level_id","report_level_value" ,"year","booths","total","male","female","total_diff","male_diff","female_diff"};
    Cursor c1=db2.query("voter_basic_info", columns, "report_level_id="+1+" and report_level_value="+221+"" ,
           null , null, null, null, null);


    return c1;

}

MainActivity


db=myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c=myDbHelper.PreviousElectionTrends1(db);
        String[] columns=new  String[]{"report_level_id","report_level_value" ,"year","booths","total","male","female","total_diff","male_diff","female_diff"};
        int[] ad1={R.id.Booths};
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        SimpleCursorAdapter ad=new SimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.datadesign ,c,columns,ad1);
         lv.setAdapter(ad);
```

Comment: First of all you have to check that all column name in table is right or not means that column id match or not.

Answer (score 0):

1. This IllegalException shows that you haven't some columns. Show you exception Stack Trace, Exceptions from SimpleCursorAdapter usually has good clear localizedMessage, call e.getLocalizedMessage().
2. Also, if you change existing db, it's hardly recommended to make "clear data" in application manager or full uninstall and install app again.
3. Please, avoid to use Deprecated constructors, try to use

   ```
   SimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to, int flags)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You must have _id column in your table. this is the main reason behind it.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.clientview);
    cdb=new ClientDatabase(this);
     Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
             stt = bundle.getString("stuff"); 
        a=stt.substring(0,(stt.indexOf("@")));
       a1=stt.substring((stt.indexOf("@")+1), (stt.length()));


    cdb.open();
    clientviewlist();
}
private void clientviewlist() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Cursor cur=cdb.getallclient(a,a1);
     String[] columnn=new String[]{ClientDatabase.CLIENT_CODE,ClientDatabase.CLIENT_NAME};
int[] to=new int[]{R.id.client1,R.id.client2};
dataaDapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.clintlist,cur,columnn,to,0);
final ListView listview=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
listview.setAdapter(dataaDapter);
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int positions,
            long id) {



      tv = (TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.client1);
         st=tv.getText().toString();
            System.out.println(st);

         Intent intent =new Intent(Client.this,Server.class);
    //  System.out.println(selectedFromList+"------------444444444444444444");




    }
});
```

and database code is

```
public class ClientDatabase {

//public static final String CLIENT_ID="_id";
public static final String CLIENT_CODE="_id";
public static final String DISTT_CODE="_distcode";
public static final String CLIENT_NAME="_name";
public static final String TOWN_CODE="_townid";
private static final String DATABASE_NAME="combinedclient.db";
private static final String TABLE_NAME="clientdata";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
public static SQLiteDatabase db;
private final Context context;
private DatabaseHelper dbheLper;
 private static final String TAG = "ClientsDbAdapter";

public ClientDatabase(Context context){
    this.context=context;
    dbheLper=new DatabaseHelper(context);

}
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

     DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null,DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME +"(" + CLIENT_CODE + " TEXT NOT NULL," + CLIENT_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL," + DISTT_CODE + " INTEGER NOT NULL," + TOWN_CODE + " INTEGER NOT NULL)");
    }//            "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME +"(" + TOWN_ID + " INTEGER  ," + TOWN_CODE + " INTEGER NOT NULL," + TOWN_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL," + DISTT_CODE + " TEXT NOT NULL," + TOWNDISTT_CODE + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY)";   

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE If EXISTS" +TABLE_NAME);
    }

}
public ClientDatabase open() throws SQLException{
    db=dbheLper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



public Cursor getallclient(String diss, String tiw) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Cursor nCursor=db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {CLIENT_CODE,CLIENT_NAME},DISTT_CODE + "='" + diss + "' AND " + TOWN_CODE +"='" + tiw + "'", null, null, null, null);
     if (nCursor != null) {
           nCursor.moveToFirst();
          }
    return nCursor;
}

public void close() {
```

dbheLper.close();
    }

```
public void insertvalues(String id, String namee, String dist,
        String townv) {
    try {
        ContentValues initial=new ContentValues();
        initial.put(DISTT_CODE,dist);
        initial.put(CLIENT_CODE,id);
        initial.put(CLIENT_NAME,namee);
        initial.put(TOWN_CODE,townv);
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, initial);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
         Log.d("Error is===", e.toString());
            System.out.println("error in insertinggggggggggggg");
    }
}

public void delete() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.delete(TABLE_NAME,null, null);
}



public String getclient(String clientcode) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Cursor cursor=db.query(TABLE_NAME, null,CLIENT_CODE + "='" + clientcode + "'", null, null, null, null); 
    if(cursor.getCount()<1) // UserName Not Exist
    {
        cursor.close();
        return "not exist";
    }
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String name= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CLIENT_NAME));
    cursor.close();
    System.out.println(name);
    return name; 


}
```